# Handle error messages with Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I have a custom validation function that I use for ensuring file size isn’t to large in my model. I upload files using carrierwave

I submit my form via ajax and if there is an error then i render my `js.erb`

```
# Document model
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :media, MediaUploader
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill

  validates :media, presence: { message: 'At least 1 File is required' }
  validate :media_size_validation, :if => "media?"

  def media_size_validation
    if media.size > 1.megabytes
      errors.add(:document, "Files should be less than 1MB")
    end
  end
end
```

Controller

```
def create
  @document = current_user.documents.new(document_params)
   respond_to do |format|
     if @document.save
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: success_save_msg }
      format.js
     else
      format.html
      format.js { render action: 'create.js.erb' }
     end
   end
 end
```

So if i upload a document with no file (:media), i get an error displayed, however if i upload a document with a file over 1mb i get

```
`Missing template documents/create, application/create`
```

Form

```
<% if @document.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation" class="alert-dismissable">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
  <h2><%= pluralize(@document.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this record from being saved</h2>
    <ul class="error_list">
      <% @document.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= error_edit(msg) %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Am i missing something here when dealing with the error if validation fails for the carrierwave image? Why would my create action not render my js.erb file?

Thanks

Comment: try changing your validation condition to a symbol. `:media?`

Comment: that hasn’t made a difference unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my own answer.

My first validation (blank form) was rendering the error messages as the form was being processed by JS:

```
Processing by DocumentsController#create as JS
```

But when I attached a file the process was then HTML

```
Processing by DocumentsController#create as HTML
```

I need to look into the specifics and intricacies with the way browsers handle the XHR request but by adding the gem `remotipart` it now works

Looking at the parameters this is within the request

```
"X-Requested-With"=>"IFrame", "X-Http-Accept"=>"text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01"}
```